# FullCalendar Scheduler Timings customization

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Is it possible in `agendaDay` view that I can start the timings from 8am instead of 12am?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to only have the `agendaDay` view start at 8am, then you can use [View-Specific Options](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/View-Specific-Options/) along with the [minTime](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/minTime/) option like so.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    views: {
        agendaDay: {
                 minTime: "8:00"
        }
    }
});
```

If you want all views to start at 8am then you would just use the minTime option in your calendar configuration like normal.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    minTime: "8:00"
});
```